# Different links for logo depending on language

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have multilingual CMS Joomla website but when I switch between languages logo anyway is pointing always to default language
I am using Gavik Pro [Template](http://demo.gavick.com/joomla25/financebusiness/) 
My live [website](http://masterprodaj.md/ro/) click on logo and it will switch to russian language but it must load Romanian default page
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't come default with your template settings, you will have to override the index.php.

Try something like the following:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();   
$logo = '<a href="index.php?' . $lang->getTag() . '"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>';
```

I'm not sure how your template displays the logo (or in which file), but find where it does, and base it on what I have provided above. The key to it is `$lang->getTag()` which will output something like **en-GB** or **fr-FR** etc

Hope this helps